# Typescript best practice in extending options passed to derived class

Tags: inheritance, typescript

I've a base class and a derived class. The derived class constructor argument (`DerivedOptions`) needs all the `BaseOptions` properties with additional ones and so I represented them as interfaces and extended it. Is the right way to do this? I also see people are using `type` to represent options passed to classes. Is there any way I can achieve this functionality using it?

```
interface BaseOptions {
   arg1: string;
}

class BaseClass {
  constructor(options: BaseOptions) { }
}

interface DerivedOptions extends BaseOptions {
   arg2: string;
}

class DerivedOptions extends BaseOptions {
   constructor(options: DerivedOptions) {
     super();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's a correct way to do it, except that you forgot to pass the options object when calling super:

```
class DerivedOptions extends BaseOptions {
   constructor(options: DerivedOptions) {
     super(options);
   }
}
```

As for using [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases), it won't work well in your case because (as stated in [Interfaces vs. Type Aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#interfaces-vs-type-aliases)):

> A second more important difference is that type aliases cannot be
>   extended or implemented from (nor can they extend/implement other
>   types). Because an ideal property of software is being open to
>   extension, you should always use an interface over a type alias if
>   possible.

So this:

```
type BaseOptions = {
   arg1: string;
}

type DerivedOptions extends BaseOptions = {
   arg2: string;
}
```

Isn't possible and won't compile with a number of errors.